# Confusing "Memory Barrier Example 1" in 《Memory Barriers: a Hardware View for Software Hackers》？

Tags: cpu-cache, memory-barriers, lockless, mesi

I am reading the great paper [《Memory Barriers: a Hardware View for Software Hackers》](https://www.puppetmastertrading.com/images/hwViewForSwHackers.pdf) written by Paul E. McKenney, which helps me a lot. But I came across a doubt in 《6.2 Example 1》:
[image: Table 2: Memory Barrier Example 1]

The author has given an explanation to the assertion firing as:

> Suppose CPU 0 recently experienced many cache
> misses, so that its message queue is full, but that
> CPU 1 has been running exclusively within the cache,
> so that its message queue is empty. Then CPU 0’s
> assignment to “a” and “b” will appear in Node 0’s
> cache immediately (and thus be visible to CPU 1),
> but will be blocked behind CPU 0’s prior traffic. In
> contrast, CPU 1’s assignment to “c” will sail through
> CPU 1’s previously empty queue. Therefore, CPU 2
> might well see CPU 1’s assignment to “c” before it
> sees CPU 0’s assignment to “a”, causing the assertion
> to fire, despite the memory barriers.

To my understanding, the CPU0's assignment to "b" will NOT appear in Node 0's cache until smp_wmb() is done in CPU0, and the smp_wmb() will block until all CPUs including CPU2 response. However, the CPU0 Message Queue is already full, so the smp_wmb() is NOT going to finish instantly as well as the CPU0's assignment to "b". This seems conflicting with the author's explanation.

In my humble opinion, I don't think this assertion in CPU2 would fire. To support it, we only need to ensure x == 1 while z == 1. Here is my reasoning:

1. If z == 1(`z=c;`), that means "c" has been assigned to 1 by CPU1;
2. Then that also means "b" has been assigned to 1 by CPU0;
3. As I stated ahead, the assignment of "a" and smp_wmb() in CPU0 must have both finished already.

Until now, we can conclude as: For CPU2, if z == 1, the assignment of "a" in CPU0 has been perceived(at least in the invalid queue of CPU2).

4. Then after the smp_rmb() of CPU2, `x=a;` will get the new value 1. That's to say, for CPU2's assertion, if z == 1 then x == 1, so it never fires.

That's my understanding, I'm kind of confused now. Could anyone help me figure it out?

As supplements, the cache system is NUCA(non-uniform cache architecture) , illustrated as:
[image: Figure 8: Example Ordering-Hostile Architecture]

Perhaps the major confusion can be abstracted to one question:
For CPU0, is it possible to execute `b=1;` if the "CPU0 Message Queue" jams?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and [mre] then edit your post.

Comment: *the CPU0's assignment to "b" will NOT appear in Node 0's cache until smp_wmb() is done in CPU0,* -- No, that's the whole point here.  It will appear in the cache IMMEDIATELY.  It won't appear in MEMORY until the wmb.  There seems to be an unstated assumption that CPU 0 and 1 are sharing a cache, but CPU 2 is not.

Comment: @TimRoberts It seems that I have missed the premise of this example, which is the "NUCA", and CPU0 and CPU1 share the same cache but CPU2 does NOT, just like you metioned. Nevertheless, I suppose smp_wmb() still ensures that the preceding store(`a==1;`) is perceived by all CPU caches(including CPU2's), and that is what cache coherency protocol guarantees. So my conclusion and reasoning are still the same.

Comment: @TimRoberts Even as you said, the assignment of "b" will appear in the cache IMMEDIATELY, but that is NOT important. As long as the smp_wmb ensures that `a=1;` precedes `b=1;` for all CPUs/caches, then the `x=a;` following smp_rwb will perceive the assignment of "a".

Comment: The WMB does not say "pause until all everything is flushed to memory".  It merely requires that things before the WMB will happen before things after the WMB.  It's still possible that CPU1 to see `b=1` from its cache before the `a=1` gets flushed to real memory, which is the only way CPU2 can see it.

Comment: I feel that I understand you now: The key point is that CPU0 will(might) NOT PAUSE until cache coherence. Thus even CPU2 perceives the `c=1;` by CPU1, it doesn't mean CPU2 also perceives the `b=1;` by CPU0, for they have different communication message queues. It's clear now. Thank you Tim^^

Comment: Perhaps the statement "until cache coherence" above is not so accurate. Caches are always in a coherent state as long as the protocol is obeyed.

Comment: A problem I see with this section 6 as a whole is that it is not explicitly stated what it means to perceive a load/store. 
In the previous section 4 using the store buffer + invalidate queue model, it is clear what it means for a store to be complete/committed: The store has been transferred from the store buffer to the cache and perhaps subsequently to main memory.

Comment: Another difference between section 4 and 6 is that: It is not clear whether store buffers are still in play in section 6, since it seems that stores from CPU0 go directly to Node0's cache without any mention of invalidate acknowledgement, e.g. from CPU2. Hence, I feel that the hypothetical model proposed in section 6 is too vague to reason about rigorously.